# for loop overextending index

Tags: android

I'm attempting to iterate through the EditText "name" and check the letters so see if they match any of the letters in the objects of the array uNamesList.
If they do I want to break out of the loop and return the placement of the object that had the matching letter. At the moment I am getting this error, anyone know what might be wrong?

```
 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9

    uNamesList.add("bob");
    uNamesList.add("mike");
    uNamesList.add("sike");
    uNamesList.add("othername");
    uNamesList.add("name");




    public int getName(EditText name) {
    String text = name.getText().toString();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) { //i = current letter in text
        char cLetter = name.toString().charAt(i);
        for (int o = 0; o < uNamesList.size(); o++) {
            String uName = (String)uNamesList.get(o);
            char uLetter = uName.charAt(i);
            if (cLetter == uLetter) {
                match = o;

                break;

            }
        }
    }
    return match;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the text inside edit text in wrong way. it should :

```
public int getName(EditText name) {
    String text = name.getText(); //get the text
    int match = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.toString().length(); i++) { //get the length of the text
        for (int o = 0; o < uNamesList.size(); o++) {
            char cLetter = name.toString().charAt(i);
            String uName = (String)uNamesList.get(o);
```

Okay, here's the edit for another problem. i dont know if this what you want.

```
public int getName(EditText name) {
    int match = 9999;
    String text = name.getText().toString();
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) { //i = current letter in text
        char cLetter = name.toString().charAt(i);
        for (int o = 0; o < uNamesList.size(); o++) {
            String uName = (String)uNamesList.get(o);
            char uLetter = uName.charAt(i);
            if (cLetter == uLetter) {
                match = o;
                found = true;
                break;

            }
        }
      if(found) break;
    }
    return match;
}
```

The simplest way is just only call return when it found.

```
public int getName(EditText name) {
    int match = 9999;
    String text = name.getText().toString();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) { //i = current letter in text
        char cLetter = name.toString().charAt(i);
        for (int o = 0; o < uNamesList.size(); o++) {
            String uName = (String)uNamesList.get(o);
            char uLetter = uName.charAt(i);
            if (cLetter == uLetter) {
                return o;
            }
        }
    }
    return match;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fix :D error gone. But also while we're on the topic, the other issue is the match that is being set to the value o is not returning, instead the pre defined value for match is always being returned. Any idea as to why this might be? I would upvote you if I could btw, just don't have enough reputation.

Comment: you need one more loop to check each letter in word of your list. your current loop will check only same index as text in your edit text. i.e text in your edit text is "kemi" and word in your list is "mike", your current loop will only check k==m e==i m==k i==e

Comment: that is what I want it to do though, it's just not returning a different "match" no matter what I type in. I think I might have screwed up the looping somehow? I'm new to java so excuse my amature questions.

Comment: why dont you just return it inside if? `if (cLetter == uLetter) {return o;}`

Comment: I tried that but it changes nothing, for some reason a return is required outside both the for loops and the value in that return is used every time.

Answer (score 0):

change your for loop to the following, you accessing name from the uNameList loop where the length might be different

```
 for (int i = 0; i < name.toString().length(); i++) {
        char cLetter = name.toString().charAt(i);  
        for (int o = 0; o < uNamesList.size(); o++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

For EditText you need GetText()

name.toString() gives you the java desciption of the object EditText

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException most likely due to this line:

`char uLetter = uName.charAt(i);`

*i* in this case can be greater than the length of *uName*